# Hiding Element Based on Toggle - Ratchet

Tags: javascript, html, css, ratchet-2

I am new to using the ratchet framework so I am probably missing something basic. I want to use a toggle to hide a div when the toggle is off, and display it when the toggle is on. I know the toggle name changes to toggle active when it's active but the code I found from a few other posts does not seem to be working in my situation. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

HTML

```
  <div class="content">
    <div id="map"></div>


    <ul class="table-view">
        <li class="table-view-cell">
            Stages
            <div id="toggle1" class="toggle">
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">
            Washrooms
            <div class="toggle ">
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">
            Foods
            <div class="toggle">
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">
            Security
            <div class="toggle">
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">
            First Aid
            <div class="toggle">
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">
            ATM
            <div class="toggle">
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Stage1" class="StageMain">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/Untitled-1.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="StageSecond">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/Untitled-1.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="StageThird">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/Untitled-1.png">
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
   if(document.getElementById("toggle1").className == 'toggle active')
    {
        $('#Stage1').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#Stage1').hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a handle to show/hide your element.

visit this link http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

check this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script>
var status = 'show';
function change()
{
 if(status == 'show')
 {
  document.getElementById("toggle1").style.display = 'none';
  status = 'hide';
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("toggle1").style.display = 'block';
  status = 'show';
 }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="content">
    <div id="map"></div>

    <ul class="table-view">
        <li class="table-view-cell" onclick="change()">
            Stages (click here)
            <div id="toggle1" class="toggle">this is test 
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="table-view-cell" >
            Washrooms
            <div class="toggle ">
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">
            Foods
            <div class="toggle">
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">
            Security
            <div class="toggle">
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">
            First Aid
            <div class="toggle">
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="table-view-cell">
            ATM
            <div class="toggle">
                <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Stage1" class="StageMain">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/Untitled-1.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="StageSecond">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/Untitled-1.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="StageThird">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/Untitled-1.png">
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for what I want to use it for, however since I'm using an on click and not the actual toggle, how would I go about re-displaying what I hid using the toggle?

Comment: I edited above answer. check it.
use   onclick="show()"  where ever you want.

Comment: Yeah, I got that part. I'm just trying to use the same toggle for both, so the first click would be hide and 2nd would be show. So the user can swap back and forth, is that possible using this technique? Again thanks so much for taking your time to answer my questions

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much I really appreciate it